# Use SQLite SELECT to combine joined table column into one row for each category using a junction table

Tags: sql, sqlite, select, group-concat, junction-table

I am using SQLite and have three tables (there is more data in these tables - abbreviated here):

- **Categories** - Holds item categories (id, name, description)
- **Items** - (id, name, status)
- **Reference** (id, cat_id, item_id)

Categories can have many items associated with it or none.
Items must have at least 1 category and may be in more than 1 category.

Example:

```
(Categories)
| id | name   | description                     |
|----|--------|---------------------------------|
| 1. | wet.   | something associated with water |
| 2. | dry.   | something else                  |
| 3. | metal. | steel, copper                   |
```

```
(Items)
| id. | name.   | status     |
|-----|---------|------------|
| 11. | river.  | north fork |
| 12. | lake.   | big        |
| 13. | river.  | south fork |
| 14. | desert. | mojave     |
| 15. | car.    | ford       |
| 16. | truck.  | chevy      |
```

```
(Reference)
| id | cat_id. | item_id |
|----|---------|---------|
| 21 | 1       | 11      |
| 22 | 1       | 12      |
| 23 | 2       | 14      |
| 24 | 3       | 15      |
| 25 | 3       | 16      |
```

Using the following:

```sql
SELECT c.name,(i.name || "-" || i.status) as Related from Items as i
join Categories c where c.id = cat.id
```

I get something that looks like this:

```
| c.name  | Related            |
|---------|--------------------|
| wet     | river - north fork |
| wet     | lake - big         |
| wet     | river - south fork |
| dry     | desert - mojave    |
| metal   | car - ford         |
| metal   | truck - chevy      |
```

What I need is

```
| c.name | Related                                            |
|--------|----------------------------------------------------|
| wet    | river - north fork, lake - big, river - south fork |
| dry    | desert - mojave                                    |
| metal  | car - ford, truck - chevy                          |
```

One category matched to the referenced items in the junction table and combined in the "Related" column (separated by comma in the example).

How do I get this result in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join `Categories` to `Reference` first and then to `Items`, with `LEFT` joins, just in case a category does not have any items related and then aggregate with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT c.name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(i.name || ' - ' || i.status, ', ') Related
FROM Categories c
LEFT JOIN Reference r ON r.cat_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Items i ON i.id = r.item_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4a2e3b1d944dd14d9ca0d77645f74cd2).
Results:

```
| name  | Related                        |
| ----- | ------------------------------ |
| wet   | river - north fork, lake - big |
| dry   | desert - mojave                |
| metal | car - ford, truck - chevy      |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `group_concat` as follows:

```
SELECT c.name, group_concat (i.name || "-" || i.status) as Related from Items as i
join Categories c on c.id = cat.id
group by c.name
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem I'm having is that the Categories and Items tables only have the Reference table to link them (many to many). I need something like  "Foreach Category => lookup all Items in the Reference table and return all Items in one column". Each Category on a separate row showing all Items associated based on the Reference table.

Comment: Yes, the updated answer will fetch the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Popeye. This does help, but I needed the reference from the junction table to pull them all in under one row (see the response from Gordon). I hope I'm not still missing your point because I really appreciate the response and don't want to discount the suggestion if I am still not seeing it. Glad to know there are so many good people out there willing to help out.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the query like this:

```
select c.name,
       group_concat(i.name || '-' || i.status, ', ') as Related
from Items i join
     Categories c 
     on c.id = i.cat_id
group by c.name;
```

Notes:

- `JOIN` should always use `ON` for the `JOIN` conditions.
- Use single quotes for strings in SQL.
- The default separator is `','`.  You seem to want `', '`, so you need the second argument.
- You need `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thanks for your post and quick response. I think there is still a missing part though - "from Items i join
     Categories c 
     on c.id = cat.id" - cat.id is not defined in the response and should come from the Reference table. In other words, I need the association with the reference table to find all of the items associated with the category.

Comment: @Vento . . . That was your original condition.  It shouldn't work in your query either.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Yes, you're right Gordon, that was my bad for sure. I see your response and really appreciate the help and feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The response from forpas was exactly what I needed. Thank you -

```
SELECT c.name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(i.name || ' - ' || i.status, ', ') Related
FROM Categories c
LEFT JOIN Reference r ON r.cat_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN Items i ON i.id = r.item_id
GROUP BY c.id, c.name
```